# Filter file and send lines in one of two files

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, ksh

I need to create two files from a single file according to the following rules : 
For each line of the input file,

- If the characters from position x to position y are all spaces, write the line in the output file A
- Otherwise, write the file to output file B

I could write this easily in ksh, but I was wondering if there isn't a better way, using grep / sed / awk or any other tool.
I'm not an expert in awk or sed but the problem is that there are two output files so I can't use flows redirections of the shell.

I read some documentation on awk and sed but couldn't find anything on the handling of several output files.

Any Ideas ?

Here is an example with x = 17 and y = 19:

Input file:

```
test.empty.field   .test
test.non.emptyfield.test
```

Output file A

```
test.empty.field   .test
```

Output file B

```
test.non.emptyfield.test
```

The input file is **not** a csv file, si I can only use character numbers to check the value. No delimiters.

Comment: sample input and expected output would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
awk -v x=10 -v y=15 '{
    out = (substr($0, x, y-x+1) ~ /[^[:space:]]/) ? "B" : "A"
    print > out
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it with `awk`

```
cat file
1234   89
123   789
123456789
```

Print to `file1` all lines with space from position `4` to `6`, rest to `file2`

```
awk 'substr($0,4,3)=="   " {print > "file1";next} {print > "file2"}' file

cat file1
123   789

cat file2
1234   89
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
pat=[[:space:]] patcol=5 n=3 fileA=A fileB=B

sed -nE "
      /^.{$((patcol-1))}$pat{$n}/ w $fileA
      //!                         w $fileB
" <<EOD
1234   89
1234  789
12345  89
EOD

cat A
cat B
```